# My question is about forks in general. If I have a portion of a coin do I get the exact portion of that new coin?

Tags: bitcoin, hardforks

my question is about forks in general. If I have a portion of coins and it gets forked do I get the exact amount of the new forked coin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the fork. Someone could create a fork that obliterates a smart contract entirely. With the [fork after the DAO](https://www.coindesk.com/ethereum-executes-blockchain-hard-fork-return-dao-investor-funds/), the contract with the ether stored in it changed; even though each user had the same ether and DAO tokens after the fork, this essentially left people with different amounts of ether at the end of the process.

Litecoin is a bitcoin fork and people with bitcoin did not automatically get litecoin after the fork.

Also, your question is tagged with "bitcoin".

Comment: yeah it was tagged with bitcoin because i was curios about bitcoin forks too

Comment: hmm thank you that mind blowing thought the process was simple

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You do get the double of coins (in the new and old blockchain) if it is a hard fork and if the fork will become a totally new currency, not just an update to the blockchain format. For this, the community supporting the currency needs to get divided by (some) convictions. If the community don't become divided, everybody will just upgrade their blockchain to a new version and you will not get your coins duplicated.